# Trying to check if properties exist with nuxt js

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, conditional-statements, nuxt.js

Hi i'm just trying to check if **{{data.name}}** exist.
if not exist just dont show this..

Iterations :

```
<div v-if="conts.Titre || conts.keys(conts.Titre).length > 0" class="communes-contenu">

<div v-if="conts.Titre != ' '" class="communes-contenu">

<h3 v-if="conts.Titre">{{ conts.Titre }}</h3>
```

But nothing... just a **"Cannot read property 'Titre' of null"**

thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Cannot read property 'Titre' of null"` means that the object that holds Titre is null

=> **conts** must be null.

You can add an additional check for the existence of `conts` in the same v-if, or wrap it around.

Option 1:

```
<h3 v-if="conts && conts.Titre">{{ conts.Titre }}</h3>
```

Option 2:

```
<template v-if="conts">
    <h3 v-if="conts.Titre">{{ conts.Titre }}</h3>
</template>
```